# Is there any finite charge distribution the potential of which doesn't decay with $\frac{1}{r}$ at infinity?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, potential

Is there any finite charge distribution the potential of which doesn't decay with $\frac{1}{r}$ at infinity? Intuitively, if you "zoom out" any **finite** charge distribution, it could be visualized as a point charge with the equivalent total charge of that distribution, meaning, its potential would decay proportional to $\frac{1}{r}$ at large distances, or is there any counterexample?

Comment: When you say finite charge, do you mean a finite number of point charges or do you allow continuous distributions such that $\int |\rho|<+\infty$? In any case, the $1/r$ decay is due to the monopole, so just take a dipole distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the charge distribution is finite in it's spatial extension and it is simple in the sense that it is composed of all positive or all negative charge, then the potential will always look like $1/r$ at far distances. However, if you have more complicated distributions, for example a positive lobe and a negative lobe, then the potential will look like a dipole potential at large distances. Similarly, one can have multipole distributions, such as quadrupoles for example.